# Find multiple categories of promises in texts

Tags: natural-language

I have conversations a customer with an agent (without punctuation). There are phrases of several categories of promises that an agent gave to a customer (call back, make an appointment, etc.). It has been done manually. Altogether 12 categories. Now I'm thinking of creating an algorithm for this. I am thinking to do this task in two steps.

1. In the first step, I need to create an algorithm that can find an
   end and a beginning of all promises. This algorithm has to insert a
   start tag and an end tag.
2. The second step is to create a classifier that would label a promise
   to the necessary categories.

As I understand, the second step is well known and this is called text classification. But for the first step, I could not find any articles and github repositories. But I think it is an important NLP task and there must be information on this. Maybe are there approaches that solve two steps at the same time?

PS
Just sample an agent's transcript (in reality it is more difficult):

```
hi my name is ben how can i help you yes good what about i can help probably yes sir do you have a problem with internet connection i see let do you need a help at place okay i see so what i can do i can arrange appointment with technical will it be good for you great can i help you with something else you okey okey to have a great day you too
```

Promise here is

```
i can arrange appointment with technical
```

Answer (score 5):

The task you are referring to is called span identification and is commonly employed in textual question answering (QA; see, e.g., [Chen, Bolton, and Manning 2016](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P16-1223.pdf); [Devlin et al. 2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf) - particularly, figure 4). If you have supervised data for span identification (as in extractive QA), you could fine-tune a pre-trained BERT model to identify the start and end tokens of a span (step 1). Then, pass the words that are within the span through another BERT model fine-tuned to classify sentences into different classes (step 2). If you don't have the annotations for true span, you may want to consider jumping straight into step 2 and not worry about extracting the span, as the latter would primarily only provide additional interpretability anyway. Note that you will need to append padding tokens to the ends of your sentences to make sure they are all of the same length.